# How to extend washing machine drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

[image: pipe]

I want to extend my washing machine drain hose as it's just 20 inches instead of at least 34 from the ground and it's lower than my washing machine. What would I need to buy to do that?

Comment: The grey hose or the black pipe?  The black pipe just needs to be cut straight and glue a coupling and another piece of black pipe on.  The grey one just need to buy a longer one from your friendly neighbourhood hardware store.

Comment: The black pipe. What type of glue would I have to use?

Comment: Which pipe cutter would be best to cut the pipe? Planning on a trip to home depot tomorrow to get all the necessary tools and the pipe

Comment: It is a plastic pipe, probably ABS(common), any hand type saw will cut it.  Check it for label/markings and/or measure it   Ask store if they have any cut off pieces or short pieces since it usually comes in long(8 or 10 foot) lengths.

Comment: I am curious, can I just remove the old pipe instead of extending it, and replace it completely? Or is it somehow connected to the P-trap?

Comment: There is a slight possibly that it is not glued to P-trap, but it should be and cutting is fastest.  Drain pipes and couplings are quite cheap.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to be a 2" ABS pipe... you will need to source a longer ABS pipe and a coupler (2" to2").  Cut the existing pipe where its cleanest,  clean up the area the coupler will go with light sandpaper, or a brillow pad, and put the new piece with the coupler on top.  (so you will need ABS Cement as well, be sure NOT to use PVC cement)

Comment: Beat me by mere moments... There appears to be a screw holding the top of the angled piece to the wall. Best to unscrew that before jamming a pry bar behind the pipe trying to get it to move.  ;) Also, make sure to _thoroughly_ clean the existing pipe. Any dirt or other gunk left in the area of the joint will make for a leaky spot. Some steel wool would work if sandpaper, Scotch-Brite™, Brillo™ or other plastic cleaning pad isn't available.

Comment: good catch on the screw,  and that's another good reason for the angle cut on the top (to facilitate wall mounting).  or, leave it straight cut and put a P-clamp to hold it to the wall...